# Find item page in PagingAndSortingRepository in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using the PagingAndSortingRepository in a classic bean to fetch a list of object.

```
Specfication s = ...
Pageable p = ..
return repository.findAll(s, p);
```

Is there a way to find out directly what page will be a given item using a given Pageable and Sort object, or have I to compute it myself ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to find out directly what page will be a given item using a given Pageable and Sort object, or have I to compute it myself?

You'll have to do that yourself. I wouldn't even know how to do that except iterating over all elements that come before the one you are looking for.

Comment: Some analyst had come with an "optimised" manual query ; using our sequencial ID, count all elements under or equals to the current one and divide by number per page